# How do I make custom data type orderable?

Tags: haskell

I have a Haskell custom data type that I would like to use as a key in `Data.Map`, `Data.Graph`, and other lookup tables.

```
data State = State
  { playerIdx :: Int
  , piles :: [Int]
  } deriving Show
```

How do I make it orderable? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
data State = State
  { playerIdx :: Int
  , piles :: [Int]
  } deriving (Show, Ord)
```

Comment: How do you consider it ordered? Given two `State`s, what determines what is the "smallest" `State` of the two.

Comment: Perform ordered comparison on playerIdx ... if equal, perform order comparison on first of both piles, then second, etc. If all are eq, then eq.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make something an instance of `Ord`, it needs to be an instance of [**`Eq`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) as well, you thus should derive both `Eq` and `Ord`:

```
data State = State
  { playerIdx :: Int
  , piles :: [Int]
  } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Comment: Thanks Willem, presumably the OP would get an error message saying "No instance for (Eq State)  arising from the 'deriving' clause ..."(?) So the lesson for @MikeRand is: don't just say "doesn't seem to work", but give us the error reported. And read that first -- it might give you the answer all on its own.